# Auto form filling using java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

My requirement is to write one script when I run the script it opens the page and fill the fields and automatically take me to next page.

For e.g. Script for www.irctc.co.in. When we login to irctc it ask the user name and password and when click on submit it redirect to next page.
I want to write a script in such a way that I just click on the script it internally does all these things and I could see the next page.

I am unable form where I should start.

Comment: You're going to have to make a coded attempt first. Google is a good place to start.

Comment: I tried search on google , when didnt find something useful posted my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like Greasemonkey: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

> Greasemonkey is a Mozilla Firefox extension that allows users to install scripts that make on-the-fly changes to web page content after or before the page is loaded in the browser.

If you use a different browser, then you can refer to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey#Equivalents_for_other_browsers

Comment: Can you please elaborate more. And i dont want to browser specific.

Comment: With Greasemonkey, you can write a userscript to do the form filling. The users will have to install it to be able to run it every time the page loads. Unfortunately, this wouldn't be browser independent. Also the user will need to have the greasemonkey plugin installed.

Answer (score 1):

Check Watir - Web Application Testing in Ruby. Although it is used for automation, it might solve the purpose here. With Watir, you write scripts in ruby and execute it and then see the magic. More information can be found [here](http://watir.com/)

Comment: Thanks for instant reply. But I am not interested in learning ruby, just want to achieve the result using Java script.

Comment: Ok, then you would have to resort to some browser plugins. Anyways it does not take much time to learn & create a script using Watir :-)

Comment: You can try Selenium, however it is commercial - more information can be found http://www.seleniumhq.org/